# Why reserved field number 19000-19999?

Tags: grpc

Why is the field number 19000-19999 reserved in gRPC? What are they reserved for? And why exactly these numbers?

I did check resources about gRPC, but on this question not had any answer.

In documentation for Protocol buffer I see just this:

> field number reserved for the protocol buffer library implementation.
> Users may not declare fields that use reserved numbers.

Comment: These are questions about the private implementation details of the gRPC library; as such they are probably only documented in the gRPC developer's documentation and/or its source code, so those would be the places to look for information.  (Note that for a user of gRPC it doesn't really matter why they are reserved; it's enough just to know that they are reserved and therefore avoid using them)

Comment: Protocol Buffers are separate from gRPC. These fields are reserved as part of the Protocol Buffers implementation, unrelated to gRPC.

Comment: Thank you guys! If I need additional information I will dig aside Protocol Buffers.